# Can i use non-tiled cement board -floor & shower shower stall?

Tags: cement, board

Ground up bathroom build on (composite board) deck. I want an industrial look/not using tile. Some leakage is OK as it will be going through deck onto soil but would like to avoid mold. If I can keep the wonderboard raw could I/should I seal it? Or a coat of diy venetian plaster? What to seal exposed seams with?

Comment: A few pictures would be helpful.

Comment: Are you going for an Eastern Bloc industrial look, or a super super cheap shower?